# Where does Quickbooks store its data?

Tags: data-recovery, finance, quickbooks

I was given a HD that has gone bad and I need to rescue the data saved by Quickbooks. Where does Quickbooks save data by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here:

http://forums.quickbooksusers.com/archive/index.php/t-24056.html

Looks like:

C:\Program Files\Intuit\QuickBooks Pro\[your company data file]

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7, the files are located at `C:/users/username/Documents/intuit/quickbooks/company files`

Answer (score 1):

The default is usually along these lines:

**C:\Program Files\Intuit\QuickBooks\Components**

but it would be easier to run a `DIR` search (or `find` on Linux) over the hard drive to see where most of the `.qbw` files are:

```
DIR /S *.qbw
```

Answer (score 0):

For Quickbooks Enterprise Solutions 14 & 17 on Windows (the versions I have run) the company file is stored in `C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Company Files` by default.

Anyone viewing this post like myself may also be interested to know that the user-specific config file for a client installation is stored at `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Intuit\Quickbooks Enterprise Solutions 17.0\QBWUSER.INI` (change the version number with your version).